# Bootstrap 3 input-group not aligned right when window resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Upgrading to Bootstrap 3 on current project. The original search bar turned into a cluster @#%$ so I decided to build it from scratch again. I dropped in an input with a button appended to it straight from the bootstrap site. Looks fine until I start resigning window. The screen shot below shows the problem. We have zoom: 115% to preserve the look of the main element on the page when resizing. I believe this may be the culprit with the single pixel offset below. Any ideas on how I can get around this? I am tempted to try and roll my input like this but I have a suspicion it will not do anything.

```
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 450px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me in `chrome`[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/a3vAP/269/)

Comment: yeah, as mentioned above I believe it's possibly related to the "zoom" on the body